# Exclude folder "web" in .htaccess does not work

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I would like to exclude the subfolder "web" in my .htaccess, but it does not work.

The .htaccess is located in the root directory. And the "web" folder is a subfolder of it.

So, I tried this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # turn empty requests into requests for "index.php",
    # keeping the query string intact
    RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !favicon.ico$

    # Folders to exclude from rewrite divided by Pipe goes here:
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /.+\/web\/.+/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Did you mean a to add a `!` in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `I would like to exclude the subfolder "web" in my .htaccess`

Have rule like this to exclude certain files or directories **before other rules**:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Folders / files to exclude from rewrite divided by Pipe goes here:
RewriteRule (^|/)web(/|$) - [L,NC]

# turn empty requests into requests for "index.php",
# keeping the query string intact
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !favicon.ico$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: thanks, it worked fine for me. I was wondering the whole night about this complex apache dialect. :-) Edit: And I think another reason was, that I used the absolute path to it and not an web server anchor.

Comment: You're welcome, yes everything in rewrite rules is starting from `DocumenRoot`